# hook_preprocess_html(&$vars) not firing

Tags: theming

I am attempting to add css classes to the body depoendant on what the page contains.

I am using the following...

```
function myTheme_preprocess_html(&$vars){
    //code here
    //eg.
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'a-new-class-for-a-node';
}
```

I cannot get this to fire or add anything to the page. It will not drupal_set_message, echo or more importantly add any classes to the body tag.

What am I doing wrong here please? I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: Which id the machine name of your theme? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: add keyword function before myTheme_preprocess_html(&$vars), ie function myTheme_preprocess_html(&$vars){...}

Comment: Thank you. I do already have function in the code. It is still not doing anything.

I also have the name of my theme where it says myTheme_preprocess_html.

Anything else I am missing out on here?

Comment: If you just added keyword function then you need to clear the cache

Comment: Thank you. I already always clear all caches when editing any code. Still nothing is happening. Can you suggest something that I can put in the function so that I know it is being called?

Comment: die('called preprocess and exited');

Comment: Try to uninstall the theme, then change the name to all lowercase, and instead use an underscore to demarcate words, such as in: my_theme. I don't know if it will help but it is worth a try. And in your code change all references to myTheme to my_theme. And just to make sure you have this function in your theme's template.php file?

Comment: Thanks for this. 
I have put die('preprocess was called!); in and nothing dies.

I do not understand it. My theme name is one word all in lowercase already. I have other preprocess functions working such as mytheme_preprocess_page, mytheme_preprocess_node, mytheme_preprocess_panels_pane and mytheme_preprocess_views_view.
Could these be preventing the mytheme_preprocess_html function from being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be terribly wrong here, but there appears to be no such hook for Drupal 6. If so, it will never fire.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6/search/hook_preprocess_html.

Perhaps you're backporting a theme from D7?

Comment: I can also not find the preprocess html hook for Drupal 6. +1. So the correct hook to add classes to body be template_preprocess_page?

Comment: Thank you. I added some code to page.tpl.php to add the classes. I will investigate using template_preprocess_page.

Comment: J.Reynolds It seems so.
@daktau As long as the code isn't anything beyond a simple if and print statements. Complex logic should go in hooks and theme functions, as you already know.